# Panel data mean exposure

Tags: function, stata, panel

I have panel data with date of birth (dt_birth), date of conception (dt_conception), gestational length (weeks_gestation and days_gestation), and daily exposure to smoke. The exposure is aligned with the date of birth. That means that the value in that row means that the smoke was measured in date of birth.

The data looks like this:

```
| dt_birth   | weeks_gestation  | days_gestation    | dt_conception | smoke
| 13/05/2010 | 35               | 224               | 10/09/2009    | 10.17825  
| 30/01/2010 | 39               | 273               | 02/05/2009    | 16.64225
| 07/06/2010 | 38               | 266               | 14/09/2009    | 25.761
| 19/03/2010 | 39               | 273               | 19/06/2009    | 11.93825
| 09/04/2010 | 40               | 280               | 03/07/2009    | 4.17875
| 04/04/2010 | 39               | 273               | 05/07/2009    | 19.454
```

Well, what I need is to calculate the average smoke exposure between conception and birth. I tried to use `egen mean_smoke = mean(inrange(dt_conception - dt_birth) * smoke)`  but it didn't work.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This does not like panel data to me. Looks like different mothers and different babies. Either way using `inrange()` within a mean call is not wrong but your `inrange()` call is quite wrong, as `inrange()` expects three arguments and you offer one (as the difference between variables is one value in each observation). I don't follow what you want to calculate but note your `mean()` implies averaging over all observations.

Comment: @NickCox , you're right. These are different mothers/babies. I should have been more clear. What I mean is that the exposure is fixed in the date of birth, but I need to average the exposure for the entire pregnancy. Like for the first row, I would average smoke data from the date of conception to the date of birth (224 days of pregnancy). 
Something like this starting from the date of birth and going backward to the day of conception: smoke+smoke[-1]+smoke[-2]... smoke[-224]/ 224
does it make sense?

Comment: I don't follow. If there's only one measurement of smoke for a pregnancy, it is already the best and only guess at an average.

Comment: @NickCox the smoke measure is from a different dataset that I merged using the date of birth and city the mother lived. so mothers how lived in the same area and gave birth on the same day will have the same measure.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, if conception is 10/09/2009 and birth is 13/05/2010 you want the average of `smoke` on all birth dates between the two? Based on how you described your inputs I am not sure whether that makes sense, but it sounds like you want to 1) reshape `dt_conception` and `dt_birth` to long; 2) `tsset` and `tsfill` on this date; 3) and merge on your daily `smoke`. Otherwise, you are conditioning your averages based on another mother in the data having given birth on that day.

Comment: Now it makes sense, thanks also to @JR96, but I think you don't start from here. You perhaps `expand` to a dataset with an observation for each day of pregnancy and then `merge` with the smoke data.